# How to add space between text and radio button?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I want single space between the text and radio button. To achieve this I tried the css class answerBottomYesNo by adding margin-left: 7px . for some reason it did not work. 
Below is code snippet

```
<div class="questionRow odd">
                <div class="question">
                    Ear Aches?
                </div>
                <div class="answers">
                    <label for="rbEarAches1"><span class="answerBottomYesNo" ><input type="radio" id="rbEarAches1" name="EarAches" value="true" data-bind="checked: EarAches">Yes</span></label>
                    <label for="rbEarAches0"><span class="answerBottomYesNo"><input type="radio" id="rbEarAches0" name="EarAches" value="false" data-bind="checked: EarAches">No</span></label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

What should I do to give a space between the radio button and text. I could have done nbsp but I really want this to reside in the CSS file. Help appreciated!

Comment: add margin in radio button {.answerBottomYesNo input[type="radio"]}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `span`, add `margin` to `input type=radio` inside the `span` like this:

```
.answerBottomYesNo input[type="radio"]{
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

See the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ageousp/

Comment: Thanks for that! Now if I want to add this same functionality for checkboxes can I add input type checkebox in same CSS class answerBottomYesNo  ? Or I would have to create a new CSS for that ?

Comment: use .answerBottomYesNo input[type="radio"], .answerBottomYesNo input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-right:20px;
} See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lcqkdd3a/1/