# How to add space between label and radio button? Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, radio-button

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31317796/4276413) but it didn't work, any advice how it can be achieved?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>Signing on behalf of</p>
    <label class="radio-inline" style="">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" checked="true" style="padding-left:15px;">A Company
      </label>
    <label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:15px;">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" style="padding-left:15px;">An Individual
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7r9nLm3b/)

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not have a closing tag. Your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `input` tag don't have closing tag, second wrap label inside `span`
>   and give it a `margin`

```css
label span{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="col-4">
      <p>Signing on behalf of</p>
      <label class="radio-inline" style="">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" checked="true" style="padding-left:15px;"><span>A Company</span>
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:15px;">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" style="padding-left:15px;"><span>An Individual</span>
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You can just separate the input and label and link them using an 'id' on the input and a 'for' attribute on the label. Then you can style your label to add the spacing.

```
<input id="company" type="radio" name="optradio" checked="true"  /><span ></span><label for="company" class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:15px;"> A Company
  </label>
```

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Insted `padding-left` use `margin-right`. And don't use closing `</input>` tag, it is auto closing like `<input />`

```css
.radio-class {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>Signing on behalf of</p>
    <label class="radio-inline" style="">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" checked="true" class="radio-class" />A Company
      </label>
    <label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:15px;">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" class="radio-class" />An Individual
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking off from Mr Belugin's idea above. This bit of css will add a right margin to all radio buttons. This solution required no additional class added to the many radio buttons in my form.

It basically adds a 4px right margin to all radio buttons.

input[type=radio] { margin-right:4px; }

Comment: I think this would be better suited as a comment to Aleksandr Belugin's answer. 
Furthermore I could see using the selector `input[type=radio]` conflicting with other radio buttons on the website in the future. The radio buttons from the question already have the class `.radio-class`, might as well utilize them.